# How to get object in different language in Jena?

Tags: java, jena, dbpedia, apache-jena

I am pulling abstract information for http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Bronx and it gives me in German, but I would like to get in English. I cannot work with SPARQL. 
Here is my code:

```
    Resource bronx=model3.getResource("http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Bronx");
System.out.println("Description:"+bronx.getProperty(model3.getProperty("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract")).getObject().toString());
```

And it prints this:
Description:Die Bronx [b????ks] ist seit dem 10. Januar 1874 der nördlichste Stadtbezirk (borough) von New York City. Er deckt sich mit Bronx County, dem am drittstärksten besiedelten County des Bundesstaates New York.@de

The question is how can I get this text in English (@en)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `abstract` is multi-valued but you asked for one object so Jena picked one, which happened to be the German ("..." @de) one.  See `listProperties` and look for the objects which are @en.  Or use SPARQL.